# Precision-Recall straight line interpretation

Tags: precision-recall

In the precision-recall curve shown, how should I interpret the straight line from 0.0 to almost 6.0?

[image]

**Update**: I include the confusion matrix where the precision and recall come from.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean "to almost 0.6"? Please explain where this precision-recall curve comes from.

Comment: @dipetkov In the recall dimension, the straight line goes to almost 0.6. In the precision one is from 1.0 to 0.7 approximately. This curve represents a binary classifier of my experiment.

Comment: What will actually help is to tell us how many positive and negative examples you have; even better it would be to provide the labels and predictions.

Comment: @dipetkov I included the confusion matrix. Does this help?

Comment: Somewhat. It's actually not particularly fun to play this guessing game... I guess that the classifier never really assigns very high scores (ie. close to 1). So when the threshold is 1, the recall is 0 and precision 1 (by default as nothing is really predicted as 1). And then the next threshold (chosen by [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html)) is much lower than 1. In any case, the classifier doesn't discriminate between the two classes very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely to (qualitatively) repeated sample instances of the positive class. About 60% of the positive instances have the same characteristics for the purposes of the classifier so either we get them  "all" in one go or nothing. That's why we go from 0 to 60 in a single step and this appears as a single step in the PR curve graph. At the same time, as we make the first "positive" classifications, we lump up some false positives so our precision goes down too.

We can see from baseline of the PR curve that more that 50% of the all samples are indeed positive (the confusion matrix corroborates that too) so the potentially "high-ish" PR-curve AUC (average precision) is not necessarily indicative of good performance. I suggest looking at the paper *[Unachievable region in precision-recall space and its effect on empirical evaluation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/3042573.3042780)* by Boyd et al. (2012) to get  more in-depth view of these implications.